# Vertical border on the left on left page and right on right pages with \AddToShipoutPicture

Tags: border

I have the following code that add some vertical border on pages but it's always on the same side (i.e. left side). So, for `twoside` documents, it won't look fine.

With the lesser changes, how to make it appear on the right on right pages and on the left on left pages?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray4}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{gray8}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{0.48cm}\rotatebox{90}{%
      \colorbox{gray8!44}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\paperheight}
          \sffamily
          \vspace*{0.4em}
          \centering
          \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
          \textcolor{gray4}{some vertical text here along the pages}
          \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
          \vspace*{0.4em}
        \end{minipage}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\newpage{}
\section{Intro}
\newpage{}
\section{Methods}
\newpage{}

\end{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: See `background` and/or `tikzpagenodes`?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but I had an issue (that I can't reproduce with my MWE, so it must be in conflict with some other package) with the `footmisc` package that I had to place before the new one in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray4}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{gray8}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{scrextend} % New package inserted !


\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
 \ifthispageodd{% define by newly inserted package ! It's an if{true}{false} structure.
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
   \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1.8cm},0){%
    \hspace*{0.48cm}\rotatebox{90}{%
      \colorbox{gray8!44}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\paperheight}
          \sffamily
          \vspace*{0.4em}
          \centering
          \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
          \footnotesize{\textcolor{gray4}{some vertical text here along the pages}}
          \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
          \vspace*{0.4em}
        \end{minipage}%
      }%
    }% 
   }%
  }%
 }%
 {
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{0.48cm}\rotatebox{90}{%
      \colorbox{gray8!44}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\paperheight}
          \sffamily
          \vspace*{0.4em}
          \centering
          \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
           \footnotesize{\textcolor{gray4}{some vertical text here along the pages}}    
          \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
          \vspace*{0.4em}
        \end{minipage}%
      }%
    }%
   }%
 }%

}%
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\newpage{}
\section{Intro}
\newpage{}
\section{Methods}
\newpage{}

\end{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```